# Trabalhando com tabelas associativas

Tags: primefaces, java

Desejo adicionar a uma tabela, os usuários que fizeram o cadastro de um time. Para que no futuro possa listar todos os times de um certo usuário.

Porem estou com o seguinte problema: Na minha tabela pessoa_time não consigo pegar o ID de quem esta criando o time nem o ID do time que esta sendo criado

A classe que executa a criação do time e a TimeBean:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "TimeMB")
@SessionScoped
public class TimeBean implements Serializable{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Time time = new Time();
    private TimeDAO dao = new TimeDAO();
    private Pessoa_Time pessoaTime = new Pessoa_Time();
    private Pessoa_TimeDAO ptdao = new Pessoa_TimeDAO();

    public TimeBean(){}

    public void cadastrar() {
        getDao().cadastrar(getTime());
        getPtdao().cadastrar(getPessoaTime());
    }

    public Time getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public void setTime(Time time) {
        this.time = time;
    }

    public TimeDAO getDao() {
        return dao;
    }

    public void setDao(TimeDAO dao) {
        this.dao = dao;
    }

    public Pessoa_TimeDAO getPtdao() {
        return ptdao;
    }

    public void setPtdao(Pessoa_TimeDAO ptdao) {
        this.ptdao = ptdao;
    }

    public Pessoa_Time getPessoaTime() {
        return pessoaTime;
    }

    public void setPessoaTime(Pessoa_Time pessoaTime) {
        this.pessoaTime = pessoaTime;
    }
}
```

LoginBean:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "LoginMB")
@ViewScoped
public class LoginBean {

    private Pessoa pessoa = new Pessoa();
    private PessoaDAO pessoaDAO = new PessoaDAO();

    // Metodo para efetuar login na aplicação
    public String efetuaLogin() {

        // Vai imprimir no console o nome do usuario logado
        System.out.println("Fazendo login do usuário " + this.pessoa.getNomeUsuario());

        // facesContext e utilizado para pegar o nome da pagina
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        boolean existe = new PessoaDAO().existe(this.pessoa);

        if (existe) {

            // Se usuario existir, armazena o usuario em usuarioLogado e mantem na sessão
            // Depois redireciona para a pagina seguinte

            context.getExternalContext().getSessionMap().put("usuarioLogado", this.pessoa);
            return "cadastrarTime?faces-redirect=true";
        }

        // Caso não exista, exibe a mensagem
        // Redireciona o usuario paga a pagina seguinte

        context.getExternalContext().getFlash().setKeepMessages(true);
        context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Usuário não encontrado"));
        return "login?faces-redirect=true";
    }

    public String deslogar() {

        // Metodo para deslogar o usuario
        // Remove o usuariologado da SessionMap

        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        context.getExternalContext().getSessionMap().remove("usuarioLogado");

        // Depois de remover ele e redirecionado para a pagina seguinte

        return "login?faces-redirect=true";

    }

    public Pessoa getPessoa() {
        return pessoa;
    }

    public void setPessoa(Pessoa pessoa) {
        this.pessoa = pessoa;
    }

    public PessoaDAO getPessoaDAO() {
        return pessoaDAO;
    }

    public void setPessoaDAO(PessoaDAO pessoaDAO) {
        this.pessoaDAO = pessoaDAO;
    }

}
```

Pessoa_Time

```
@Entity
public class Pessoa_Time implements Serializable{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    @ManyToOne
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="id_pessoa", referencedColumnName="id_pessoa")
    private Pessoa pessoa;
    @ManyToOne
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="id_time", referencedColumnName="id_time")
    private Time time;

    public Pessoa_Time(){}

    public Pessoa_Time(Pessoa_Time pt){
        this.id = pt.getId();
        this.pessoa = pt.getPessoa();
        this.time = pt.getTime();
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public Pessoa getPessoa() {
        return pessoa;
    }
    public void setPessoa(Pessoa pessoa) {
        this.pessoa = pessoa;
    }
    public Time getTime() {
        return time;
    }
    public void setTime(Time time) {
        this.time = time;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Pessoa_Time [id=" + id + ", pessoa=" + pessoa + ", time=" + time + "]";
    }
}
```

Time:

```
@Entity
public class Time implements Serializable{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column (name="id_Time")
    private int id;
    @Column(nullable=false)
    private String nome;
    @Column(nullable=false)
    private String senhaTime;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="time",cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Pessoa_Time> pessoas;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="time",cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Pessoa_Time> campeonatos;

    public Time(){}

    public Time(Time time){
        this.id = time.getId();
        this.nome = time.getNome();
        this.senhaTime = time.getSenhaTime();
        this.pessoas = time.getPessoas();
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public List<Pessoa_Time> getPessoas() {
        return pessoas;
    }

    public void setPessoas(List<Pessoa_Time> pessoas) {
        this.pessoas = pessoas;
    }

    public List<Pessoa_Time> getCampeonatos() {
        return campeonatos;
    }

    public void setCampeonatos(List<Pessoa_Time> campeonatos) {
        this.campeonatos = campeonatos;
    }

    public String getSenhaTime() {
        return senhaTime;
    }

    public void setSenhaTime(String senhaTime) {
        this.senhaTime = senhaTime;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Time [id=" + id + ", nome=" + nome + ", senhaTime=" + senhaTime + ", pessoas=" + pessoas
                + ", campeonatos=" + campeonatos + "]";
    }


}
```

TimeDAO:

```
public class TimeDAO {

    private EntityManager em;


    public TimeDAO() {
        setEm(JPAUtil.getEntityManager());
    }

    public void cadastrar(Time time){
        getEm().getTransaction().begin();
        getEm().persist(time);
        getEm().getTransaction().commit();
    }


    public List<Time> listaTodosTimes(){
        Query q = em.createQuery("select t from Time t");       
        List<Time> times = q.getResultList();
        return times;
    }

    public void atualizar(Time time){
        getEm().getTransaction().begin();
        getEm().merge(time);
        getEm().getTransaction().commit();
    }

    public void remover(Time time){
        getEm().getTransaction().begin();
        getEm().find(Time.class, time.getId());
        getEm().persist(time);
        getEm().getTransaction().commit();
    }

    public EntityManager getEm() {
        return em;
    }
    public void setEm(EntityManager em) {
        this.em = em;
    }
}
```

Pessoa:

```
@Entity
public class Pessoa implements Serializable{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column (name="id_Pessoa")
    private Integer id;

    @Column()
    private String nomeUsuario;

    @Column()
    private String senhaUsuario;

    @Column()
    private String nomeCompleto;

    @Column()
    private String email;

    @Column()
    private Integer idade;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="pessoa",cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Pessoa_Time> times;

    public Pessoa (){}

    public Pessoa (Pessoa pessoa){
        this.id = pessoa.getId();
        this.nomeUsuario = pessoa.getNomeUsuario();
        this.senhaUsuario = pessoa.getSenhaUsuario();
        this.nomeCompleto = pessoa.getNomeCompleto();
        this.email = pessoa.getEmail();
        this.idade = pessoa.getIdade();
    }



    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNomeUsuario() {
        return nomeUsuario;
    }

    public void setNomeUsuario(String nomeUsuario) {
        this.nomeUsuario = nomeUsuario;
    }

    public String getNomeCompleto() {
        return nomeCompleto;
    }

    public void setNomeCompleto(String nomeCompleto) {
        this.nomeCompleto = nomeCompleto;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public Integer getIdade() {
        return idade;
    }

    public void setIdade(Integer idade) {
        this.idade = idade;
    }

    public List<Pessoa_Time> getTimes() {
        return times;
    }

    public void setTimes(List<Pessoa_Time> times) {
        this.times = times;
    }

    public String getSenhaUsuario() {
        return senhaUsuario;
    }

    public void setSenhaUsuario(String senhaUsuario) {
        this.senhaUsuario = senhaUsuario;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Pessoa [id=" + id + ", nomeUsuario=" + nomeUsuario + ", senhaUsuario=" + senhaUsuario
                + ", nomeCompleto=" + nomeCompleto + ", email=" + email + ", idade=" + idade + ", times=" + times + "]";
    }
}
```

PessoaDAO:

```
public class PessoaDAO {

    private EntityManager em;


    public PessoaDAO() {
        setEm(JPAUtil.getEntityManager());
    }

    public void cadastrar(Pessoa pessoa){
        getEm().getTransaction().begin();
        getEm().persist(pessoa);
        getEm().getTransaction().commit();
    }

    public void atualizar(Pessoa pessoa){
        getEm().getTransaction().begin();
        getEm().merge(pessoa);
        getEm().getTransaction().commit();
    }

    public List<Pessoa> listaTodasPessoas(){
        Query q = em.createQuery("select p from Pessoa p");     
        List<Pessoa> pessoas = q.getResultList();
        return pessoas;
    }

    // Metodo que vai verificar se os dados informados pelo usuario são validos

    public boolean existe(Pessoa pessoa) {

        // Realizar uma consulta com os parametros informados pelo usuario

        String consulta = "select u from Pessoa u where u.nomeUsuario = :pUsuario and u.senhaUsuario = :pSenha";
        Query query=getEm().createQuery(consulta);

        query.setParameter("pUsuario", pessoa.getNomeUsuario());
        query.setParameter("pSenha", pessoa.getSenhaUsuario());

        // Se for verdadeiro, resultado recebe a pessoa

        try {
            Pessoa resultado = (Pessoa) query.getSingleResult();
        } catch (NoResultException ex) {
            return false;
        }

        em.close();

        return true;
    }

    public void removerPessoa(Pessoa pessoa){
        getEm().getTransaction().begin();
        getEm().find(Pessoa.class, pessoa.getId());
        getEm().remove(pessoa);
        getEm().getTransaction().commit();  
    }


    public EntityManager getEm() {
        return em;
    }
    public void setEm(EntityManager em) {
        this.em = em;
    }
}
```

Comment: Atualmente quando faço o registro de um time, ele chega a gerar um id de pessoa_time porem o pessoa_id_Pessoa e time_id_Time vem nullo para o banco de dados.

Comment: Cara vc quer adicionar uma auditoria? Se sim, olha o `Hibernate Envers`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente o seguinte.

ao invés de em Pessoa

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="pessoa",cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Pessoa_Time> times;
```

crie um

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "times_pessoas")
private List<Pessoa_Time> times;
```

e em Time ao invés de:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="time",cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Pessoa_Time> pessoas;
```

Crie

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "times")
private List<Pessoa_Time> pessoas;
```

Com isso a JPA ira criar e controlar a entidade times_pessoas não sendo necessario criar a classe Pessoa_Time.